Which metrics are best for comparing annual PM2.5 concentrations across different sites?
The US EPA's National Ambient Air Quality Standards (NAAQS) provide methods for determining compliance with health standards based on PM2.5 air quality monitors.  Concentrations are averaged across days, quarters, and/or years.  The daily PM2.5 NAAQS of 35 μg/m3 uses a 98th percentile, so the 8th highest daily average over a year is used as the benchmark of meeting the air quality standard (averaged across 3 years).  For the annual standard of 9 ug m/3, the annual averages are calculated from 3-month averages (averaged across 3 years).
While the EPA methods create a straightforward approach to determining attainment of the standard, it does not provide a metric for the long-term exposure that someone would've experienced in outdoor air.  Higher concentrations of PM2.5 can have a much greater effect on health, discussed in "concentration response function" literature.
Can a concentration response function (or some other function) be used to create a metric for comparing PM2.5 exposures at different sites?  Such a metric would hopefully use one year of data, and weight hourly (or daily) concentrations appropriately (considering health effects) before integrating them into a single value.  In general, which metrics are best for comparing PM2.5 exposure across different sites?
